# How to find the image location

Tags: php, mysql

```
 move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key], "img/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key])
```

the above code shows that the new location of my image is

`"img/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]).`

How can i store this in a variable so that I can pass this location in mysql database for the purpose of retrieving the image.

Comment: Do **NOT** use this code. You are opening your system to a total remote compromise, by allowing anyone to upload a file ANYWHERE they want on your server. As for your actual question, `$var = 'img/' . $_FILES[etc....`.

Comment: @MarcB Because of `[$key]`?

Comment: @MarcB Please provide him more informations when you mention security problems

Comment: @freq: no, because OP's using the user-provided `['name']` parameter directly in the move operation. that does NOT get filtered and can contain pathing information.

Comment: @MichaelWalter Or "her". Usual term is "OP", just to be on the safe side. We don't know the OP's gender.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks Marc, I will remember that. So, is it because of it being a generic word, is that why? And should it (`name`) be replaced by a variable instead?

Comment: @MarcB i did this to store the path :   $var = "img/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);   BUt it gives error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'.

Comment: @MarcB thanks for the advise. I will keep it in mind

Comment: @MarcB Any suggestions as to a safe method that the OP or anyone else can use? Maybe a couple of keywords to Google?

Comment: upload, hijack, sanitize, validate, and for fun, though it's not the case XSS. Looking for that will get you tons of other stuff.

Comment: @Anthony Thanks for the keywords, will definitely and seriously look into that subject. Cheers

Comment: @Fred - Thank you for reading up on it, you make it safer for everybody when you avoid the scary stuff. Here's a great post on SQL injection that helped me along the way : http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I don't know if this passes the security test, yet have found [**this article**](http://phpsense.com/2007/php-file-uploading/) on the subject.

Comment: @Anthony You're welcome and it's indeed a pleasure Anthony. Thanks for the link, going there now. Have a look at the link/comment I posted just above this one.

Answer (score 0):

Because the filename set in the `name` value is based on user-provided filename and because you don't do any apparent sanitizing of the content or the name, the user could upload a file that is executable by apache and give it a name like:

`../../../wickedevilnaughtyfile` and get it in the host system's root directory or similar nasty place it doesn't belong and it could be executed from the web browser since http server (apache or whatevs) has access to it since it created the file.

This isn't an actual answer, but as demanded in the comments, security threats need more than 600 characters to explain sometimes

BTW, if I missed anything in this somewhat terse explanation or got something just wrong, feel free to edit and sign your name right in the answer.

Comment: As I `@'ed` Marc, Any suggestions as to a safe method that the OP or anyone else can use? Maybe a couple of keywords to Google? Some useful information would be beneficial for all who would stumble on this question.